# How to dump the stack and heap of a running application to determine if zeroization is occuring?

Tags: linux, memory, proc, virtual-memory, core-dump

I am trying to ensure that after the use of sensitive parameters, a program zero-es them from all active memory (stack and heap). The simple test I was hoping to perform was to dump the active memory to a flat file while it was running (after it should have zero'd the sensitive parameters). Then i would just binary grep the flat file for the parameter. If it is not there success else failure.

If there are existing tool that can generate just a dump of the stack and heap? No other data like profiling info or symbols.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is usually called a *core dump*. Your kernel has the ability to trigger these built-in, and it's a common thing to be done automatically (through `systemd-coredump`) when your program segfaults.

You can also make a core dump manually, using a debugger. `gdb` is pretty much the standard debugger under linux:

```bash
shell> gdb --args /path/to/your/executable --sensible-arg1 -s 2 --sensible-arg3 foobar
[…]
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1, main(argc=6, argv=…)
(gdb) break the_function_at_which_you_want_to_break
(gdb) continue
[…]
(gdb) generate-core-file
Saved corefile core.123456
(gdb) quit
```

Now you have a corefile in which you can operate to your liking.

Honestly, I find `radare2` to be the tool of choice to inspect process memory (you can do the same as above directly in radare2)

```bash
shell> radare2 -d /path/to/your/executable --sensible-arg1 -s 2 --sensible-arg3 foobar
[0x7f44444]> aaa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Finding and parsing C++ vtables (avrr)
[x] Skipping type matching analysis in debugger mode (aaft)
[x] Propagate noreturn information (aanr)
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
[0x7f44444]> db sym.the_function_at_which_you_want_to_break
[0x7f44444]> dc
[0x7f44444]> e search.in=dbg.maps
[0x7f44444]> / the_needle_you're_looking_for
0x7f524662c3ed hit1_0 some_more_dirty_stuff the_needle_you're_looking_for
…
[0x7f44444]> s hit1_0
[0x7f524662c3ed]> pr
some_more_dirty_stuff the_needle_you're_looking_for Things go really downhill from here…
```

Radare2 is nice because it's really meant for memory analysis, and looking for things like cryptographic secrets in memory. For example, it has an excellent entropy display, with which you can often spot things like secret keys in binaries, or compressed data in memory.

On the flip side, I had to look up all the commands myself... it's a highly specialized tool with it's own mechanics.

Comment: definitely going to use these as a fall back, but after looking into this more it seem that i should be able to read from `/proc/self/map` then `/proc/self/mem` and get what i need (cause i just need a dump). If i get this working i'll submit an answer; else accept yours.